# Using Meteor's settings.json to connect to local MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I was breaking out some of the admin/management functionality from a Meteor app into another new one to cut down client app size/help restrict access. I also have MongoDB installed separately on localhost and in production.

I've been able to run each app on separate ports and to connect to the DB passing environment variables as I start the apps:

```
# App 1
MONGO_URL=mongodb://localhost:27107/appDB meteor 
# App 2
MONGO_URL=mongodb://localhost:27107/appDB meteor --port 4000
```

Of course, I'd like to use `settings.json` in the project root to pass these variables in rather than having to specify them (here's the `settings.json` for App 2):

```
{
    "env": {
        "PORT": 4000,
        "MONGO_URL": "mongodb://localhost:27017/appDB"
    }
}
```

And using `meteor run --settings settings.json` to pass these variables in. However, Meteor won't recognise the settings file. Any ideas where I might've gone wrong?

**Update 1:**
@Apendua was kind enough to let me know that `settings.json` simply doesn't support this behaviour yet. Setting up bash aliases instead.

**Update 2:**
@AshHimself pointed out that Galaxy can recognise environment variables in this fashion, but the [core Meteor docs](https://guide.meteor.com/deployment.html#environment) weren't terribly clear if this works in a local environment.

Comment: To my knowledge there's currently no way to set port and `MONGO_URL` within `settings.json`. Using environment variables is the only option for now.

Comment: Ah, ok. So I suppose I'd be better served by setting up some bash aliases for the commands, then providing the env. variables as part of my deployment process?

Comment: Seems reasonable ...

Comment: Great—I'll update the question as necessary, and might throw up a feature request or something. Thanks @apendua !

Comment: For those coming from Google. You can now do this. http://galaxy-guide.meteor.com/deploy-guide.html

Answer (score 2):

I run my Meteor app with local MongoDB with bash script.

Go to your Meteor project directory and write this in your command line (BASH):

```
echo 'MONGO_URL=mongodb://localhost:27017/meteorprojectname meteor run' > run.sh
```

Change permissions of the script so you can run it without sudo:

```
sudo chmod 777 run.sh
```

And now you can just run your project with command:

```
./run.sh
```

More info: http://meteor.hromnik.com/blog/meteor-run-without-creating-local-mongo-database

Comment: Is there a way to easily change the Meteor port number without editing the `run.sh` file? Quite often I run several copies of meteor at the same time on different ports. `./run.sh --port 4000` does not work.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me very well. The only changes I would make is just adding execution permissions only, and I dumped the `.sh` off the filename.

```
echo 'MONGO_URL=mongodb://localhost:27017/meteorprojectname meteor run' > run
sudo chmod +x run
./run
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not as fancy as a shell script, but...this one liner alias works too.

```
alias <myapp>="export MONGO_URL=mongodb://<mongohost>:<port>/<database>; meteor run"
```

Of course, sub everything in brackets to your taste and rejoice.